# react trying to set multiple values with an onclick button

Tags: reactjs

When the user clicks a payment method card it should set the values of the usestates to the respective values.

How do I assign multiple values in the onClick button function? Thanks.

```
<div className="col-md-auto" key={p.id}>
    <div className="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
        <div className="card-body">
            <p className="card-text"><b>{p.card_number}</b></p>
            <p className="card-text"><b>{p.expiry_date}</b></p>
            <p className="card-text"><b>{p.cardholder_name}</></p>
            <p className="card-text"><b>{p.sort_code}</b></p>
            <p className="card-text"><b>{p.cvv_number}</b></p>
            <div className="btn-group mr-2">
                <button
                    onClick={e => setExpiry_date(p.card_number),setExpiry_Date(p.expiry_date)}>
                    Click me!
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like you're already doing it?

Comment: @TJ it doesn't work. it gives the following error TS18007: JSX expressions may not use the comma operator. Did you mean to write an array

Comment: @DanielOlsen the expiry date doesn't have a card number?

Comment: How about add a curly bracket and call two function inside? ```onClick={e => {setExpiry_date(p.card_number); setExpiry_Date(p.expiry_date);}}```?

Comment: @ikhvjs i get the error Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression when compiling.

Comment: I fixed it i was missing a ;

Comment: Please add details of errors you get in question description beforehand

Answer (score 0):

I think having a handler might make it a bit more readable and you might be getting the errors because of the syntax and some missing commas.

I don't know if it's a mistake, but you are doing `setExpiryDate` twice in your handler for both card number and expiry date. I think there should be two different values. Will you mind sharing your whole component code for more clarity?

Also, try to use `camelCase` for all handers, some linters might not allow snake cases and React also uses camelCase itself.

Can you see if the following works for you.

```js
const Component = () => {

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setCardNumber(cardNumber);
    setExpiryDate(expiryDate);
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>
      Click me
    </button>
  ); 

}
```